# How TO - Filter/Search Table in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Search table using pure javascript. I had tried below function. What's wrong in this function?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

       if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       }else{
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}
#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem your code seems to work

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  //filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  filter = '1'
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
      else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 1000)
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```